# How to read the data and the associated field name that is in a filled-in PDF form

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pdf-form

I am writing a python script that needs to pull the data filled in a PDF form as part of a larger script. I tried using pyPDF3 but while it can show me the strings in the form, it does not show the filled-in data. I have a form where I have entered the value 'XXX" into a field and I want the script to be able to return that data and the name of the field but I can't seem to read the data. The fillpdfs module is very helpful but AFAICT it can return the field names but not the data.
I have this snippet:

```
    from PyPDF3 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
    # Open the PDF file
    pdf_file = open('filename.pdf', 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

   # Extract text data from each page
   for page_num in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
    'XXX' in page.extractText()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function for pdf forms:

```
dictionary = pdf_reader.getFormTextFields() # returns a python dictionary
print(dictionary)
```

[Documentation](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfReader.getFields)

Comment: That's very helpful. Is there a way to get the value of checkboxes as well?

Comment: pdf_reader.getFields() gives you a dictionary with a value ‘Yes’ if it is checked and a blank if not. Please accept the answer, if this answer your question. I added a link to the documentation in my answer above.